# Exporting contacts

Tags: android

Can someone tell me how the contacts.apk application does the "export" functionality. Does it read each and every row of the contacts.db using cursors and then convert them into .vcf. This seems to be painfully slow, but the application seems to be doing this much faster. It would be great if someone can point me to the code that does the "export" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The Android source code is on [android.git.kernel.org](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/contacts/ExportVCardActivity.java).